# On Test Failure, WebDriverEventListener's method "beforeGetScreenshotAs" is running continously. What will be the best implementation for this method?

Tags: java, selenium, webdrivereventlistener

I am trying to implement WebDriverEventListneter for customized log and test steps into report file but during test execution- on Fail  method "beforeGetScreenshotAs"  is running infinetly. Refer below for my WebDriverEventListneter's code:

```
public class WebEventListener extendsBaseTest implements WebDriverEventListener {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebEventListener.class.getName());
    ExtentReports extent = ExtentManager.getInstance();

    public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("Action performed on element ");

    }

    public void afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("Clicked on element");
    }

    public void afterFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("Element found By " + arg0.toString());
    }

    public void afterNavigateBack(WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("Navigating to Back  " + driver.getCurrentUrl());

    }

    public void afterNavigateForward(WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("Navigating to Back  " + driver.getCurrentUrl());

    }

    public void afterNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("Navigating to url  " + arg0);

    }

    public void afterScript(String arg0, WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("Remote WebDriver executed Script" + arg0);

    }

    public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("Action is performing on " + element.getText());
    }

    public void beforeClickOn(WebElement arg0, WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("About to click on the " + arg0.toString());
        logger.info("About to click on the " + arg0.toString());

    }

    public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver driver) {
        logger.info("About to Find By on the " + arg0.toString());

    }

    public void beforeNavigateBack(WebDriver driver) {
        logger.info("Just before beforeNavigateBack " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        System.out.println("Just before beforeNavigateBack " + driver.getCurrentUrl());

    }

    public void beforeNavigateForward(WebDriver driver) {
        logger.info("Just before beforeNavigateForward " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        System.out.println("Just before beforeNavigateForward " + driver.getCurrentUrl());

    }

    public void beforeNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Just before beforeNavigateTo " + arg0);
        logger.info("Just before beforeNavigateTo " + arg0);
    }

    public void beforeScript(String arg0, WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Just before beforeScript " + arg0);
        logger.info("Just before beforeScript " + arg0);
    }

    public void onException(Throwable error, WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Exception occured at " + error);
        try {
            TestUtil.takeScreenshot();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void beforeAlertAccept(WebDriver driver) {
        logger.info("Accepting Alert");

    }

    public void afterAlertAccept(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            logger.info("Alert accepted");
        } catch (Exception E) {
            logger.error("Failed to Accept alert!");
        }

    }

    public void afterAlertDismiss(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            logger.info("Alert is dismissed");
        } catch (Exception E) {
            logger.error("Failed to Dismiss alert");
        }

    }

    public void beforeAlertDismiss(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            logger.info("Trying to dismiss alert");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Not able to dismiss alert");
        }

    }

    public void beforeNavigateRefresh(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            logger.info("Going to refresh Page!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to refresh page");
        }

    }

    public void afterNavigateRefresh(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            logger.info("Page Refreshed !");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to refresh page");
        }

    }

    public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver, CharSequence[] keysToSend) {
        try {
            logger.info("Going to enter text : " + keysToSend + "in field" + element.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to enter text");
        }

    }

    public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver, CharSequence[] keysToSend) {
        try {
            logger.info("Entered text : " + keysToSend + "in field");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to enter text");
        }

    }

    public void beforeSwitchToWindow(String windowName, WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            logger.info("Going to switch window" + windowName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("unable to switch window" + windowName);
        }

    }

    public void afterSwitchToWindow(String windowName, WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            logger.info("Switched into window" + windowName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("unable to switch window" + windowName);
        }

    }

    public <X> void afterGetScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> target, X screenshot) {
        logger.info("Captured screenshot afterGetScreenShot As ");

    }

    public void beforeGetText(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            logger.info("Getting Text from " + element.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to get Text" + element.getText());
        }`
    }

    public void afterGetText(WebElement element, WebDriver driver, String text) {
        try {
            logger.info("Text found " + element.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Faied to get Text" + element.getText());
        }

    }

    public <X> void beforeGetScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> target) {

        logger.info("Capturing screenshot " + target.toString());

    }
}
```

On Failure, I am getting infinite log on console:

```
Session ID: dc5a3e7f94d464a0588c8db7678f772e
2019-11-26 16:49:13 INFO  WebEventListener:226 - Capturing screenshot OutputType.FILE
2019-11-26 16:49:13 INFO  WebEventListener:226 - Capturing screenshot OutputType.FILE
2019-11-26 16:49:13 INFO  WebEventListener:226 - Capturing screenshot OutputType.FILE
```

Please suggest best implementation of method `public <X> void beforeGetScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> target)`